# Hide figures in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have written a loop which has this code (from EEGLAB):

```
[spectra,freqs] = spectopo(filesx(i,:), 0, 100);
```

and it produces a figure hundreds of times. Is there a way to tell MATLAB to not show the figure at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 'plot' option to turn them off.

```
[spectra,freqs] = spectopo(filesx(i,:), 0, 100,'plot','off');
```

Here's a [reference to the function](http://cognitrn.psych.indiana.edu/busey/temp/eeglabtutorial4.301/allfunctions/spectopo.html).

Answer (score 2):

One option is to clear the figure at the end of each iteration with

> clf

if you want to see the figure in each iteration. But if you prefer don't see the figure and you only want to save it, you could try:

> set(fighandle, 'visible','off')
>   saveas(fighandle,'file.fig','fig')

and open it later when you need it.

If you post your code I could try to help you.